# difference between "fair" and "equitable"

Tags: vocabulary

I saw two words of "fair" and "equitable" in one sentence in a standard of practice.

is there any difference between them?

if yes what is that?

Comment: Related, on the EL&U sister site: [What's the difference between “null” and “void” in legal language?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/18189/142322)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> fair

has more a meaning of moral treatment

> She was treated unfairly.
>   *she was not treated correctly*

> equitable

has more a meaning of financial division

> the proceeds of the sale was divided equitably amoung the stakeholders
>   *the money from the sale was divided fairly amoung the stakeholders*

> if something is divided *equitably* it is usually considered to be divided *fairly*

You might have come across a phrase like

> fair and equitable

it means to divide something which is morally correct and financially correct.

Comment: does it mean fair refer to justice but equitable refer to equity?? and they are the same always.

Comment: The use of *equitable* may be from *equity* since it may also refer to a division of *wealth*